# TypeError when using Gspread

Tags: python

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import math

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("nerd test score-4859b437be96.json", scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

sheet = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r5vjJSB76JJq--cmPV6D36PYVFlL4-1N96cBchavawA/edit#gid=365689118')
response = sheet.sheet1
print(response.row_count)
print(response.cell(2,2))
count = response.row_count -1
response.add_rows(int(1))
sheet2 = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mLq6ofk2rhuPtju8jAGEY15zJdFRw9UL2q9vSw7Vin0/edit#gid=0')
result = sheet2.sheet1
print(response.cell(2,10))
def split(cell) :
parts=cell.rsplit("'")
length=len(parts)
print(parts)
if length != 3 :
    parts=cell.rsplit('"')
    print(parts)
return parts
```

is returning

`es\gspread\client.py", line 76, in _ensure_xml_header
    if data.startswith('<?xml'):
    TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str`

I tried adding b to `if data.startswith('<?xml')` but that returns `gspread.exceptions.HTTPError: 400: b'Content is not allowed in prolog.'` How do I fix this?
Edit sorry that I had only the one bit of code. it is making me add more words now.

Comment: [gspread master branch at GitHub](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/client.py#L76) has different code for line where exception occurs. Most likely you are using older (non Python 3 compliant) version of package in your Python 3 interpreter.

Comment: yeah im using a branch that supports row deletion that explains it

Answer (score 0):

Side note: It may be easier to read the sheet response object as a list by including the .get_all_values() method :

```
response = sheet.sheet1.get_all_values()
response.append ( new_row_to_add )
```

Comment: so sorry about that.

Comment: What line in your code is causing the Traceback Error that you included?

Comment: Response.add_rows(int(1))